# CSS links not working for responsive design

Tags: css, iphone, responsive-design

So I'm creating a responsive design website depending on the users device, however when viewing the site on an iPhone 5C the css link for the smartphone version `css/smartphone/header.css` doesn't work, and neither does the tablet `css/tablet/header.css` file. It just shows the desktop version on the mobile phone (which I don't want). But when I view the site on the Google Developer 'Dimensions' extension, which allows you to mimic a mobile device (in this case the iPhone 5), the css links work as intended.

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my css links which causes them to not work on the iPhone 5? Thank you

`<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 1024px)' href='css/desktop/header.css' />
<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 767px)' href='css/smartphone/header.css' />
<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px)' href='css/tablet/header.css' />`

Comment: Most likely the device's min-width exceeds 1024px and thus uses the desktop CSS

Comment: I hope now it's working :)

Answer (score 0):

Try: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />`. For more info, see this article on MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag.

Comment: Figured out my own question. Went back and put ALL my css into just one css file. Then did trial and error with media queries until I got the desired effect. Also took the advice of @Luis Assuncao , in addition to making the view non-user-scalable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use some solid device specific media queries when building responsive websites.
In your case the media queries are not the right ones for iphone.

For instance you could use these ones as a starting point and then if needed you can search for other resources online.

```
/*
* From css-tricks.com
* http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/
*/

/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Here you can find a more extensive list with specific devices: http://nmsdvid.com/snippets/